# Hangman game. Why won't the dashes show?

Tags: javascript, html

The dashes don't appear to represent the letters in the word. They're supposed to initiate when the start function is activated from clicking the play button.

```
<html>
<head>
<img src="images/hangman_large.png" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
<h1>Hangman</h1>
<h3>theStatus</h3>
<h4>theDashes</h4>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

var guessInt = 6;
var guessStr = "You have " + guessInt + " tries left"; 

    // Randomly select a word from the Array
    function getWord()
    {
         var words = new Array("Number","Goblin","Prestidigitation","Invigorating","Radio",
    "Bromine","Bosnia","Catastrophe","Manic","Marble",
    "Granite","Georgia","Forlorn","Monster","Blasphemy");

    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    return words[index];
    }

    // Given a string, "word", return a hidden version of it consisting of dashes for the display.      
    function getDisplay(word)
    {   
        var display = "";

    for (var i=0; i < word.length; i++)
    {
        display = display + "-";
    }

    return display;
    }

            // word is an object and search is a default function part of object word
    // Given the word "word", check if it contains the letter "letter".
    // FIND IF THE LETTER IS IN THE WORD
    function isLetterInWord(word, letter)
    {       

             /* Write an if conditional to check if the variable word is null OR 
       the value of guessInt equals 0 */
   if (word === null || guessInt === 0)
    {
        return;// Return program control with a return statement
    }
    else
    {
        /* Write an if conditional that calls the search function on variable word 
           passing variable letter as an argument and use the logical compound not 
           operator and equality (!=) to compare the result to -1, -1 indicates that 
           it doesn't exist */
        if(word.search(letter) != -1)
        {   
            setLetter(word, letter, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML);
            // Call function setLetter(word, letter, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML);
        }
        else
        {
            // letter was not in the word so decrease the number of tries left and update the display
            guessInt--;// Decrement global variable guessInt by 1
            guessStr="You have " + guessInt + " tries left";
            // Update global variable guessStr based in the updated value of guessInt
            document.getElementById("guesses").innerHTML = guessStr;
            // Update element id "guesses" to the updated guessStr
        }
        isFinished(word, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML, guessInt);
        // Call function isFinished( word, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML, guessInt );
        }
    }

    //UPDATE GAME DISPLAY IF WE'VE BEEN GIVEN A MATCHING LETTER
    // This method is called by the Hangman program when your isLetterInWord function above returns true.
    // The parameters passed in are the guessed letter, the secret word, and the current display state of the secret word.
    // This method will return a new display state of the secret word based on the matching letter.

    function setLetter(word, letter, display)
    {
        /* Write an if conditional to check if the variable word is null OR 
           the value of guessInt equals 0 */
        if(word === null || guessInt === 0)
    {
        return;// Return program control with a return statement
    }
    else
    {
        /*  Write a repetition statement that calls the search function on variable word 
            passing variable letter as an argument and use the logical compound not operator 
            and equality (!=) to compare the result to -1 */
        while(word.search(letter) != -1)
        {
            // Create variable index and set it equal to the search function call on variable 
            //  word passing variable letter
            var index = word.search(letter);
            display = display.substr( 0, index ) + letter + display.substr( index + 1 );
            word = word.substr( 0, index ) + '-' + word.substr( index + 1 );
        }

        display = index;// Update the display
        document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML = display;
            // Update element id "theDashes" to the updated display variable
        }
    }

    // This method is called each time you guess a letter. Its job is to determine whether you have have won the game, lost the game,
    // or if the game should continue.

    // The input parameters passed are the secret word (word), the current word display (display), and the number of chances left (left)
    // to reveal the secret word.

    function isFinished(word, display, left) 
    {
        // Write a conditional statement checking to see if the value of left is greater than 0
        if(left > 0)
    {
        // Write a conditional statement checking to see word is equal to display
        if(word == display)
        {
            document.getElementById("theStatus").innerHTML = "Congratulations! You won!";// Update element id "theStatus" and set it equal to "Congratulations! You won!"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* Update element id "theStatus" and set it equal to "HANGMAN! Your man has been hanged! -->
           The word was and concatenate the variable word */
           document.getElementById("theStatus").innerHTML = "HANGMAN! Your man has been hanged!";
    }
        }
    }

    // This is the main function that runs the program
    **function start()
    {
        // TODO reset variable guessInt set equal to 6
        guessInt = 6;
    // reset guessStr
    guessStr = "You have " + guessInt + " tries left";
    // create a variable called word set equal to function call getWord()
    var word = getWord();
    // create a variable called display set equal to function call getDisplay() passing variable word as an argument 
    var display = getDisplay(word);
    // update HTML object id "guesses" so it equals variable guessStr
    document.getElementById("guesses").innerHTML = guessStr;
    // update HTML object id "theWord" so it equals variable word
    document.getElementById("theWord").innerHTML = word;    
    // update HTML object id "theDashes" so it equals variable display
    document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML = display;   
    // update HTML object id "theStatus" so it is empty for a new game
    document.getElementById("theStatus").innerHTML = "";    
    }**

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<body style="background-color:green"> 
<FORM NAME="game">
<PRE>
<TEXTAREA NAME="status" ROWS="7" COLS="16"
ONFOCUS="stayAway()"></TEXTAREA>
</PRE><P>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="toGuess"
ONFOCUS="stayAway()"> <h1> theWord</h1><BR>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="guessed"
ONFOCUS="stayAway()"> <h2>guesses<h2><BR>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="A" id="A" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord('A')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="B" id="B" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord('B')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="C" id="C" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'C')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="D" id="D" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'D')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="E" id="E" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'E')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="F" id="F" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'F')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="G" id="G" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'G')"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="H" id="H" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'H')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="I" id="I" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'I')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="J" id="J" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'J')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="K" id="K" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'K')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="L" id="L" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'L')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="M" id="M" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'M')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="N" id="N" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'N')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="O" id="O" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'O')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="P" id="P" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'P')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="Q" id="Q" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'Q')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="R" id="R" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'R')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="S" id="S" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'S')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="T" id="T" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'T')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="U" id="U" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'U')"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="V" id="V" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'V')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="W" id="W" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'W')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="X" id="X" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'X')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="Y" id="Y" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'Y')"/></td>
        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="Z" id="Z" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'Z')"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <input type="submit" style="width:150;height:50" value="Play" id="play" class="restart" onclick="start()"/>
</div>
<div style="width:400px;float:left;">
    <h2>Let's Play!</h2>
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;float:left;">
<h3 id="guesses"></h3>
<h2 id="theDashes"></h2>
<!-- Update <h2 id="theWord"> with attribute hidden="true" so the selected word is not displayed -->        
<h2 id="theWord" hidden="true"></h2>
<h3 id="theStatus"></h3>
<br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see two open tags for the `body` element, and tags outside of your body tag that cannot be there (img, etc), an empty script tag, and inconsistencies in captial and lower case tags

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a LOT of problems.   I cleaned it up enough to get the dashes to show.  The dark dashes don't show up real well on the green background but they are there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

        var guessInt = 6;
        var guessStr = "You have " + guessInt + " tries left";

        // Randomly select a word from the Array
        function getWord()
        {
            var words = new Array("Number","Goblin","Prestidigitation","Invigorating","Radio",
       "Bromine","Bosnia","Catastrophe","Manic","Marble",
       "Granite","Georgia","Forlorn","Monster","Blasphemy");

            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
            return words[index];
        }

        // Given a string, "word", return a hidden version of it consisting of dashes for the display.
        function getDisplay(word)
        {
            var display = "";

            for (var i=0; i < word.length; i++)
            {
                display = display + "-";
            }

            return display;
        }

        // word is an object and search is a default function part of object word
        // Given the word "word", check if it contains the letter "letter".
        // FIND IF THE LETTER IS IN THE WORD
        function isLetterInWord(word, letter)
        {

            /* Write an if conditional to check if the variable word is null OR
      the value of guessInt equals 0 */
            if (word === null || guessInt === 0)
            {
                return;// Return program control with a return statement
            }
            else
            {
                /* Write an if conditional that calls the search function on variable word
                   passing variable letter as an argument and use the logical compound not
                   operator and equality (!=) to compare the result to -1, -1 indicates that
                   it doesn't exist */
                if(word.search(letter) != -1)
                {
                    setLetter(word, letter, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML);
                    // Call function setLetter(word, letter, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML);
                }
                else
                {
                    // letter was not in the word so decrease the number of tries left and update the display
                    guessInt--;// Decrement global variable guessInt by 1
                    guessStr="You have " + guessInt + " tries left";
                    // Update global variable guessStr based in the updated value of guessInt
                    document.getElementById("guesses").innerHTML = guessStr;
                    // Update element id "guesses" to the updated guessStr
                }
                isFinished(word, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML, guessInt);
                // Call function isFinished( word, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML, guessInt );
            }
        }

        //UPDATE GAME DISPLAY IF WE'VE BEEN GIVEN A MATCHING LETTER
        // This method is called by the Hangman program when your isLetterInWord function above returns true.
        // The parameters passed in are the guessed letter, the secret word, and the current display state of the secret word.
        // This method will return a new display state of the secret word based on the matching letter.

        function setLetter(word, letter, display)
        {
            /* Write an if conditional to check if the variable word is null OR
               the value of guessInt equals 0 */
            if(word === null || guessInt === 0)
            {
                return;// Return program control with a return statement
            }
            else
            {
                /*  Write a repetition statement that calls the search function on variable word
                    passing variable letter as an argument and use the logical compound not operator
                    and equality (!=) to compare the result to -1 */
                while(word.search(letter) != -1)
                {
                    // Create variable index and set it equal to the search function call on variable
                    //  word passing variable letter
                    var index = word.search(letter);
                    display = display.substr( 0, index ) + letter + display.substr( index + 1 );
                    word = word.substr( 0, index ) + '-' + word.substr( index + 1 );
                }

                display = index;// Update the display
                document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML = display;
                // Update element id "theDashes" to the updated display variable
            }
        }

        // This method is called each time you guess a letter. Its job is to determine whether you have have won the game, lost the game,
        // or if the game should continue.

        // The input parameters passed are the secret word (word), the current word display (display), and the number of chances left (left)
        // to reveal the secret word.

        function isFinished(word, display, left)
        {
            // Write a conditional statement checking to see if the value of left is greater than 0
            if(left > 0)
            {
                // Write a conditional statement checking to see word is equal to display
                if(word == display)
                {
                    document.getElementById("theStatus").innerHTML = "Congratulations! You won!";// Update element id "theStatus" and set it equal to "Congratulations! You won!"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                /* Update element id "theStatus" and set it equal to "HANGMAN! Your man has been hanged! -->
                   The word was and concatenate the variable word */
                document.getElementById("theStatus").innerHTML = "HANGMAN! Your man has been hanged!";
            }
        }


        // This is the main function that runs the program
        function start()
        {
            // TODO reset variable guessInt set equal to 6
            guessInt = 6;
            // reset guessStr
            guessStr = "You have " + guessInt + " tries left";
            // create a variable called word set equal to function call getWord()
            var word = getWord();
            // create a variable called display set equal to function call getDisplay() passing variable word as an argument
            var display = getDisplay(word);
            // update HTML object id "guesses" so it equals variable guessStr
            document.getElementById("guesses").innerHTML = guessStr;
            // update HTML object id "theWord" so it equals variable word
            document.getElementById("theWord").innerHTML = word;
            // update HTML object id "theDashes" so it equals variable display
            document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML = display;
            // update HTML object id "theStatus" so it is empty for a new game
            document.getElementById("theStatus").innerHTML = "";
        }

    </SCRIPT>
</head>



    <body style="background-color:green">

<PRE>
<TEXTAREA NAME="status" ROWS="7" COLS="16"
          ONFOCUS="stayAway()"></TEXTAREA>
</PRE><P>
                <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="toGuess"
                       ONFOCUS="stayAway()"> <h1> theWord</h1><BR>
                <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="guessed"
                       ONFOCUS="stayAway()"> <h2>
                    guesses
                </h2>
                <BR>
                <table border="1" style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="A" id="A" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord('A')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="B" id="B" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord('B')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="C" id="C" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'C')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="D" id="D" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'D')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="E" id="E" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'E')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="F" id="F" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'F')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="G" id="G" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'G')" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="H" id="H" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'H')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="I" id="I" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'I')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="J" id="J" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'J')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="K" id="K" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'K')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="L" id="L" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'L')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="M" id="M" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'M')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="N" id="N" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'N')" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="O" id="O" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'O')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="P" id="P" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'P')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="Q" id="Q" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'Q')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="R" id="R" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'R')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="S" id="S" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'S')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="T" id="T" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'T')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="U" id="U" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'U')" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="V" id="V" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'V')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="W" id="W" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'W')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="X" id="X" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'X')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="Y" id="Y" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'Y')" /></td>
                        <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="Z" id="Z" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'Z')" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <input type="button" style="width:150;height:50" value="Play" id="play" class="restart" onclick="start()" />

                <div style="width:400px;float:left;">
                    <h2>Let's Play!</h2>
                    <div style="width:200px;height:200px;float:left;">
                        <h3 id="guesses"></h3>
                        <h2 id="theDashes"></h2>
                        <!-- Update <h2 id="theWord"> with attribute hidden="true" so the selected word is not displayed -->
                        <h2 id="theWord" hidden="true"></h2>
                        <h3 id="theStatus"></h3>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>

    </body>
</html>
```